# Failing to display a custom WPF dialog box more than one time

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, modal-dialog

I am trying to display a custom dialog box multiple times using the following code:

```
        TestWindow newTestWindow = new TestWindow(test);
        newTestWindow.Owner = this;
        newTestWindow.ShowDialog();
```

And I get the following exception when running the code above for the 2nd time:

```
Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you are trying to display the same element in both dialogs (maybe the test parameter)? You would need to disconnect the element from the dialog when it's closed, so that it can be used in any subsequent dialogs.

Comment: Absolutely! You are right, thanks. I thought that when GC removes those objects all those object are disconnected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Test _newTestWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded);
    }

    private void OnLoaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        _newTestWindow = new Test { Owner = this };
        _newTestWindow.ShowDialog();

        _newTestWindow = new Test { Owner = this };
        _newTestWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```